# NatTable width inside a CTabItem

Tags: java, nattable

I have a CTabFolder which has many CTabItems.  Each CTabItem has a different NatTable as its control. When each NatTable is created, it has column headers but no rows.  When I click on a "Populate Data" button, it will populate each table with data.

If I view each tab before I click the "Populate Data" button, I will see the column headers as expected.  I can then push the button and see all the data correctly populated in all the tables.

If I DO NOT view tab(s) before I click the "Populate Data" button, I will not see any column headers or data (for the tabs that I did not previously view).  This is because the NatTable in that tab has a width is 0.

I do not want to have to click on every tab before clicking the "Populate Data" button.  What call is being made internally (that I might manually have to call) to correctly set the NatTable width when the tab is not focused.

Below is my code sample:

```
public void whenNatTableIsCreated(){
    // Make sure the table fills the width of the parent
    glazedListsGridLayer.getBodyDataLayer()
        .setColumnPercentageSizing(true);
    nattable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration() {
        {
            cellPainter = new LineBorderDecorator(new 
                TextPainter(false, true, 5, true));
        }
    });

}
public void afterTableHasData() {
    // Now that we have data, turn off the percentage sizing and 
    // allow the table width to exceed the parent width

    // This fails because getNatTable().getWidth() is 0
    getGlazedListsGridLayer().getBodyDataLayer().setDefaultColumnWidth(
            getNatTable().getWidth() / getGlazedListsGridLayer().
            getBodyDataLayer().getColumnCount());
    getGlazedListsGridLayer().getBodyDataLayer()
        .setColumnPercentageSizing(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the sample I don't understand the usage of percentage sizing. I suppose this is the issue. You enable it initially but the parent composite doesn't has a size, therefore the width of all columns is set to 0. By enabling it again the column widths are not automatically set to some width and stay 0.

The width of the table is derived from the columns. In case of the ViewportLayer the width is maxed to the available client area. But as all columns have a width of 0, the width of the whole NatTable is 0. And setting the default column width after percentage sizing was enabled will probably also not lead to the result you expect, because there is a size value for every column stored, which overrides the default width.

In short, your whole idea doesn't seem to work with NatTable.

Comment: I use percentage sizing to make sure the column names span the entire parent width. Without that call they do not.  If someone is looking at the tables before they are populated with data, I want to show the table as the same width as the parent (even though there is no data, there are still column names showing)